# Stored Procedure Related

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I am creating a stored procedure in oracle that is selecting records from login table -

```
create or replace procedure login_info
    (username IN varchar2, password IN varchar2, result OUT number)
as
begin
    select * from login;
end;
```

Whenever I am going to compile this it shows an error:

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

What does this mean? I do not understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the result of your SELECT statement into a variable, you can use sys_refcursor to display the result.

```
create or replace procedure login_info
    (username IN varchar2, password IN varchar2, result OUT number, result_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
l_query varchar2(1000) := Null;

begin
  l_query :=  'select * from login';
open result_out 
for l_query;
end;
```

above code will give you the output

Answer (score 0):

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

That means you need an `INTO` close when you issue bare `SELECT`  from PL/SQL.

:D

---

More constructively: where do you think the result of your select would go in that code fragment?

```
create or replace procedure login_info
    (username IN varchar2, password IN varchar2, result OUT number)
as
begin
    select * from login;
end;
```

You have to retrieve it somehow in order to be processed by your PL/SQL code. Assuming you have several rows to collect, you should use [`BULK COLLECT INTO`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html):

```
create or replace procedure login_info
    (username IN varchar2, password IN varchar2, result OUT number)
as
    type my_tbl_type IS TABLE OF login%ROWTYPE;
    my_tbl my_tbl_type;
begin
    select * BULK COLLECT INTO my_tbl from login;

    -- do whatever you
    -- need here
    -- on `my_tbl`.
end;
```

---

As a final note, maybe are you looking for an explicit `CURSOR` instead? You should definitively take a look at [PL/SQL 101: Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html). This is an interesting discussion both about `SELECT ... INTO ...`  and `CURSOR` manipulation.